# When is it necessary to implement Fabric high-throughput to avoid key collisions?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, chaincode

I am trying to implement a token in Fabric with low TPS. According to [high-troughput sample](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/high-throughput) I must consider key collisions and try to avoid using the same keys for accounts. Due to the difficulty of implementation, I want to know that is it necessary to implement high-throughput? For how many TPS I need to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

If a transaction with a new value of an asset is submitted before the previous one hasn't been committed yet to the ledger, an MVCC conflict occurs.
This happens because multiple transactions are trying to update at the same asset before they are committed to the ledger.

If your solution needs to update an asset at the same time you should follow the best practice suggested in the [high-throughput chaincode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/high-throughput/chaincode/high-throughput.go) example by using [composite keys](https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.4/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#createCompositeKey__anchor).

Comment: When it becomes necessary to implement that? I mean how much tx per sec?